# Javascript run a function at the same time with different vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Sorry about the confusing title, I'll explain better.
I have a 20x20 grid of div's, so its 400 of them each with an id, going from 0 to 399.

Each div is given one of three random values - red, green or blue - and when a div is clicked, a function is run to check if the div to the left, right, over and under are of the same value, if it is of the same value it will be simulated a click and the same function will run again.

The problem, is that the function sets vars, so if it finds that the div below has the same value, it will overwrite the vars set by the first click, hence never click any of the others.

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5e52s/

Here is what I've got:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en">  
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>untiteled</title>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 420px;
        }
        .box {
            width: 19px;
            height: 19px;
            border: 1px solid #fafafa;
            float: left;
        }

        .box:hover {
            border: 1px solid #333;
        }

        .clicked {
            background: #bada55 !important;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>

        $().ready(function(){
            var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
            var i = 0;
            while(i<400){
                var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                $('.test').append('<div class="box" id="'+i+'" value="'+color+'" style="background:'+color+';">'+i+'</div>');
                i++;
            }

            $('.box').click(function(){
                var t = $(this);
                t.addClass('clicked');
                id = t.attr('id');
                val = t.attr('value');

                //Set color

                up = parseInt(id) - 20;
                right = parseInt(id) + 1;
                down = parseInt(id) + 20;
                left = parseInt(id) - 1;
                clickup = false;
                clickdown = false;
                if($('#'+down).attr('value') === val){
                    clickdown = true;
                }
                if(up > -1 && ($('#'+up).attr('value') === val)){
                    clickup = true;
                }

                if(clickdown == true){
                    $('#'+down).click();
                }
                if(clickup == true){
                    $('#'+up).click();
                }







            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="test">

    </div>      
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the biggest root cause of your problem is you don't check if it already has class 'clicked' or not. That could make the infinite recursive. For example, if you click on the div#2 then the div#1 receives a simulated click, and div#2 receives a simulated click from div#1.

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    var t = $(this);
    if(t.hasClass('clicked')) {
        return;
    }

    t.addClass('clicked');
    var id = t.attr('id');
    var val = t.attr('value');

    //Set color

    var up = parseInt(id) - 20;
    var right = (id%20 != 19) ? ((0|id) + 1) : 'nothing' ;
    var down = parseInt(id) + 20;
    var left = (id%20 != 0) ? ((0|id) - 1) : 'nothing';

    console.log(up, right, down, left);

    if($('#'+down).attr('value') === val) {
       $('#'+down).click();                    
    }
    if($('#'+right).attr('value') === val) {
       $('#'+right).click();                    
    } 
    if($('#'+up).attr('value') === val) {
       $('#'+up).click();                    
    }
    if($('#'+left).attr('value') === val) {
       $('#'+left).click();                    
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, you are so right! I didn't see this at all! Well done man, thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the clicks onto the event loop instead of calling them directly, eg:

```
            if(clickdown == true){
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $('#'+down).click();
                });
            }
```

I don't think that's your root cause though, it's probably a combination of global vars and scope issues. Try reformatting as such:

```
$('.box').click(function (event){
    var t = $(this), id, val, up, right, down, left, clickup, clickdown;
    //...
```

Comment: This sounds right, but even when I do var foo, bar, etc; Its stops after the first if($(direction).attr('value') === val)){} and then continues on to the next click

Answer (score 0):

Your variables `id` and `val` are not in a `var` statement, thus are implicitly created as members of the `window` object instead of being scoped to the local function. Change the semicolon on the line before each to a comma so that they become part of the var statement, and your code should begin working.

Comment: Its a good suggestion, but for some reason, it makes no difference.